# Python: I don't understand why my code randomly gives the wrong answer

Tags: python

I'm writing a code to shift all the zeros in an array to the end. However, I do not understand why it gives me the wrong answer.

My solution was to check every array element if it was zero, and if it was, pop it and append another zero.

```
def move_zeros(lst):
    x = 0 
    while x < len(lst):
        if lst[x] == 0:
            lst.pop(x)
            lst.append(0)
        x += 1
    return lst
```

However, sometimes for some reason, my code just ignores a zero. For example, here are some test cases in which my code failed:
[0, 2, 0, 0] should equal [2, 0, 0, 0]
[9, 0, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] should equal [9, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Here are the inputs for the sample test:
[9, 0, 0, 9, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9], and I am supposed to return [9, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Can someone please help me understand which part of my code did I screw up in?

Comment: You are only "allowed" to increment `x` if you did not find a 0 - if you found a 0 and shift it you need to check the same index `x` again, and again and again ... until there is no more 0 at that index.

Comment: It's difficult to mutate a list at the same time as iterating over it. [0, 0, 1] is a minimal program which your code gets wrong -- perhaps you can step through it by hand?

Comment: A better approach is to first remove all zeros, and as the final step is to add a list of the zeros back.

Comment: thank you luk2302 for your help! I was careless and failed to notice that I was changing the position of all the other elements in the list, therefore causing my code to fail! I fixed this problem by appending into another newlist so the original wouldn't be affected. thank you so much!

Comment: Also @senkyte, if you aren't incrementing the index, you'll be stuck in an infinite loop, especially at the end of the list, if there's a zero at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all of your responses! Thanks to all of you, I managed to see the careless mistake I overlook in my code; that the array's position were changed due to the appending and popping. My solution was to instead append lst[x] if lst[x] != 0, and then add the zeros by using lst.count(0) in a while loop. Here is my final code; it's a bit more clunky compared to the improved codes you all gave me:

```
def move_zeros(lst):
x = 0
zerocount = 0
newlist = []
while x < len(lst):
    if lst[x] != 0:
        newlist.append(lst[x])
    x += 1
while zerocount < lst.count(0):
    if lst.count(0) == 0:
        break
    else:
        newlist.append(0)
        zerocount += 1
return newlist
```

Again, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

Since you manually increment indices as you loop through a list, it may be less error prone to use a `for` loop.

```py
def move_zeros2(lst: list):
    for elem in lst:
        if elem == 0:
            lst.remove(0)
            lst.append(0)

    return lst
```

You can also make an even smarter implementation that doesn't at all modify the list while looping over it, that sorts based on if the value is zero or not like so:

```py
def move_zeros3(lst: list):
    return sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x == 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this carefully in-place in linear time and O(1) space, by shifting elements down in the array:

```
def move_zeros(xs):
    j = 0
    for x in xs:
        if x != 0:
            xs[j] = x
            j += 1
    for i in range(j, len(xs)):
        xs[i] = 0
    return xs
```

Try to avoid using pop, because repeated calls to pop are likely to cause your program to run in quadratic time (ie: O(n^2)).

On an input list of `[0] * 500000` this code runs in 0.067s, whereas a solution using pop will run in around 22s (at least on my machine).

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code lies in the logic of the `while` loop combined with the use of `pop` inside the loop. When you encounter a zero and use `lst.pop(x)`, it modifies the original array by removing the zero at index `x`. However, this action shifts the remaining elements to the left, and the next iteration of the loop skips the element that was shifted to the current index `x`. As a result, some zeros may be skipped and not properly moved to the end of the array.

To fix this issue, it's recommended to iterate over the array in reverse order so that removing elements doesn't affect the loop traversal. Here's an updated version of your code that addresses this problem:

```
def move_zeros(lst):
    x = len(lst) - 1
    while x >= 0:
        if lst[x] == 0:
            lst.pop(x)
            lst.append(0)
        x -= 1
    return lst
```

In this update code, the loop starts from the last index `(len(lst) - 1)` and goes backwards until index 0. This ensures that removing elements from the list doesn't disrupt the iteration process.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, NubDev! Many or most of your 23 answers in the last two weeks appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.